# How to run javascript function from aspx page?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have written some code there are 27 different functions that execute like this..

```
    ElseIf websiteID = 15 Then
                    parserTravelPost(hotelURL, hotelID, websiteID)
                    nextPageLink = ""
                ElseIf websiteID = 16 Then
                    parserTripAdviosr(hotelURL, hotelID, websiteID)
                    nextPageLink = ""
                ElseIf websiteID = 17 Then
                    parserTripTake(hotelURL, hotelID, websiteID)
                    nextPageLink = ""
                ElseIf websiteID = 18 Then ........
```

After every function i want a literal or any other way to tell the function is finished...
example after the first function finish , the literal should shows example finished now starting function 2 ...

Any help/tips/code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simplay response.write the javascript code or you can use registerclicentscriptBlock in asp.net

//vb version

```
Dim scriptText As String
    scriptText = "return confirm('Do you want to submit the page?')"
    ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Me.GetType(), _
        "ConfirmSubmit", scriptText)
```

hope it helps.

Comment: yup, this will run when compiler executes the line.